# RadioGroup.setEnabled(false) doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-widget

I have used `setEnabled(false)` to set it unable, but it doesn't work and after this method, the value of `RadioGroup.isEnabled()` is false. The value was changed.

The code is from Android Programming Guide.

PS: The `Spinner` component use the `setEnabled(false)` as well.

Code is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class TestRadioGroup extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radiogroup);

    final RadioGroup testRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.testRadioGroup);

    final Button changeEnabledButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeEnabledButton);
    changeEnabledButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeEnabled(testRadioGroup);
        }
    });

    final Button changeBgColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeBackgroundColorButton);
    changeBgColorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeBgColor(testRadioGroup);
        }
    });

}

protected void changeBgColor(RadioGroup testRadioGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    testRadioGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}

protected void changeEnabled(RadioGroup testRadioGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (testRadioGroup.isEnabled()) {
        testRadioGroup.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        testRadioGroup.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Iterate and disable each button belonging to the radio group via a loop, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    testRadioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: ,thank you very much!And,em,the second method actually works well.It disabled all the RadioButton！But the first still doesn't work! Does the code work well on your machine?

Comment: Is this a design flaw in Android? RadioGroup is a subclass of View, which inherits the method, what does setEnabled even do for it?

Comment: I've the same doubt @ScriptKitty . Checked that it has no effect on the `radioButton` i.e. of its child! Can anybody explain why so?

Answer (score 4):

Views can be compose by multiple touchable elements. You have to disable them all, like this:

```
for(View lol : your_spinner.getTouchables() ) {
    lol.setEnabled(false);
}
```

If it is a simple one since it also returns itself:

> Find and return all touchable views that are descendants of this view, possibly including this view if it is touchable itself.

[View#getTouchables()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTouchables%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the following code;

```
for(View lol : your_spinner.getTouchables() ) {
    lol.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Once the views has disabled, there is no touchable child/descentant views anymore.