# Radio Button In Android Enable and Disable

Tags: java, android

I used radio button for language selection.

- English
- Hindi
- Tamil

When I click English the radio button of English should be disabled.
Again I should not able to click the English radio button till I click the next language it 
should be in disabled position.
In Java code I need.I created the xml file.

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: Sounds weird... Clicking a radio button should disable it? Hardly makes sense to me.

Comment: Why with radio button, its only one select no meaning to disable

Answer (score 15):

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonEng).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button btnEng=(Button)findviewById(R.id.btnEng);
    btnEng.setEnabled(false);
}
});
```

Is this what you asked for? If yes, then that's the code. Then just re-enable it when the other buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 2):

To enable and Disabled Radio Group write this code.

```
// To disabled the Radio Buttons of radio group.
        for (int i = 0; i < radioUser.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioUser.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        }
```

where **radioUser**=**RadioGroup**

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
 private void Disable_Or_Enable_RG_Button(RadioGroup radioGroup,boolean enable_or_disable){
    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(enable_or_disable);
    }
}

 Disable_Or_Enable_RG_Button(rg_group,false) // for disable all radio button.
 Disable_Or_Enable_RG_Button(rg_group,true) // for enable all radio button.
```

Answer (score 1):

Activate a click listener for the radioButton by setting radioButton.setOnclickListner for that radioButton and then call the radioButton.setEnabled(false) method inside the listener.
You will have to do this for each Tamil,English and Hindi radio buttons individually.

Answer (score -1):

You can use radio button group for this. It will be better option.

Comment: Will u guys give more clearly.Radio group will disable all radio buttons i need single radio button to be disabled

Comment: Samadhan's suggestion doesn't seem to work. I tried `final RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup1); radioGroup1.setEnabled(false);` but it doesn't disable the buttons in the group

Comment: To disable a group, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261602/radiogroup-setenabledfalsenot-working

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution

1. myRadioButton.isClickacle(false) in java
2. myRadioButton.isClickable = false in kotlin